# Change combobox items when another combobox selecteditem changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have two `ComboBox` in the View. I want to change the second one itemsources when the first one selecteditem is changed:

**The View:**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsList}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedProduct}" DisplayMemberPath="ChipName"/>
```

**The ViewModel:**

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        GetProductsList();
    }

    ProductDb pd = new ProductDb();
    public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductsList { get; set; }
    private void GetProductsList()
    {
        try
        {
            ProductsList = new ObservableCollection<Product>(pd.GetProducts());
        }
        catch(Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); }
        if (ProductsList != null) SelectedProduct = ProductsList[0];
    }
```

**The Model read data from xml:**

```
public class ProductDb
{
    public ObservableCollection<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Product> _products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@".\Config\Chip.xml");
        foreach(XElement productRow in doc.Root.Elements("Chip"))
        {
            var p = new Product(productRow.Element("ChipName").Value, productRow.Element("Series").Value, productRow.Element("Type").Value,
                Convert.ToUInt32(productRow.Element("FlashAddress").Value), Convert.ToUInt32(productRow.Element("PageCount").Value), Convert.ToUInt32(productRow.Element("PageSize").Value),
                Convert.ToUInt32(productRow.Element("RAMAdd").Value, 16), Convert.ToUInt32(productRow.Element("RAMLength").Value, 16), productRow.Element("Crystals").Value);

            foreach (XElement crystal in productRow.Element("Crystals").Elements())
            {
                p.Crystals.Add(crystal.Value);
            }
            _products.Add(p);
        }
        return _products;
    }
}
```

Now the above code populate the `ChipName` in the first combobox, I want to display the `Craystal` of the `SelectedProdu` in the sencond combobox. how should I do? Thanks in advance!

---**Update:**---

Crystals is an element of Product. It contains several Crystal. The xml file looks like this:

```
<System>
  <Chip>
    <ChipName>Hxxxxxxx</ChipName>
    <Series>CM0+</Series>
    <Type>0</Type>
    <FlashAddress>00000000</FlashAddress>
    <PageCount>256</PageCount>
    <PageSize>512</PageSize>
    <RAMAdd>20000000</RAMAdd>
    <RAMLength>0x1800</RAMLength>
    <Crystals>
      <Crystal>4</Crystal>
      <Crystal>6</Crystal>
      <Crystal>8</Crystal>
      <Crystal>10</Crystal>
      <Crystal>12</Crystal>
      <Crystal>16</Crystal>
      <Crystal>18</Crystal>
      <Crystal>20</Crystal>
      <Crystal>24</Crystal>
      <Crystal>32</Crystal>
    </Crystals>
  </Chip>
</System>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work provided that you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `SelectedProduct` property:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedProduct.Crystals}" />
```

This should also work provided that `Crystals` is a public property of the `Product` class:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="a" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsList}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedProduct}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="ChipName"/>

<ComboBox x:Name="b" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Crystals, ElementName=a}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Somthing like what you have already for products, but need to tell UI where to find the new item source for the new combo:

XAML:

```
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Crystals}" 
            SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCrystal}" 
            DisplayMemberPath="CrystalName"/>
```

C#:

```
public Product SelectedProduct
{
  set 
    {
       // your private member setting...
       // raise property change for crystal collection for UI to respond
    }
}

public Product SelectedCrystal
{
  set 
  {
     // your private member setting...
     // raise property change for crystal collection for UI to respond
  }
}

public ObservableCollection<Crystal> Crystals
{
  get 
    {
       if (SelectedProduct != null)
         return SelectedProduct.Crystals;

       return new ObservableCollection<Crystal>();
    }
}
```

If you like, you can also play with either visibility or enabled state of the crystal control based on whether there are any valid objects in its bound collection...

Comment: Crystals is an element of Product. It contains several Crystal. I don't have a single Type for Crystal

Answer (score 0):

xaml:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="ChipName"/>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Crystals}" />
```

c#:

```
public class MainModel:INotifyPropertyChanged    
{   
        event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  
        ObservableCollection<Product> _ProductsList = null;  
        ObservableCollection<Crystal> Crystals = null;  
        Product _SelectedProduct = null;

    public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductsList   
    {
        get
        {
            return _ProductsList;
        } 
        set
        {
            _ProductsList=value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("ProductsList")); 
        }
    }  

    public ObservableCollection<Crystal> Crystals    
    {
        get
        {
            return _Crystals;
        } 
        set
        {
            _Crystals=value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("Crystals")); 
        }
    } 

    public Product SelectedProduct
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedProduct;
        }
        set
        {
            _SelectedProduct = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedProduct")); 
            ResetCrystals();
        }
    } 
    private void ResetCrystals()
    {
         Crystals=.....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you tried something like this:

```
<StackPanel>
        <ComboBox Width="100" Height="22" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsList}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedProduct}" DisplayMemberPath="ChipName"/>
        <ComboBox Width="100" Height="22" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedProduct.Crystals}"  DisplayMemberPath="Value"/>    
</StackPanel>
```

For me, this worked well, i just set `Product.Crystals` as ObservableCollection, and did `SelectedProduct` with `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface

As example:
View Model:

```
        public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductsList { set; get; }
        public Product SelectedProduct
        {
            set
            {
                _selectedProduct = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
            get
            {
                return _selectedProduct;
            }
        }
```

Model:

```
public class Product
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Crystal> Crystals { set; get; }
        public String ChipName { set; get; }
        public Product(ObservableCollection<Crystal> l, String ChipName)
        {
            this.ChipName = ChipName;
            Crystals = l;
        }
    }

    public class Crystal
    {
        public string Value { set; get; }
    }
```